# React native RecordScreen Native Module is null

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-native-module

I want to use RecordScreen NativeModule in my react native app.

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native'
console.log(NativeModules) // This is empty {}
console.log(NativeModules.RecordScreen) // This is null
```

Currently I'm testing on android device `yarn android` build.

What is the reason for `NativeModules` is empty and `NativeModules.RecordScreen` is null ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import {requireNativeComponent} from 'react-native';
const RecordComponent = requireNativeComponent('RecordComponent')

console.log(RecordComponent);
```

Try this instead
or if you wish to use the same one you can also do it like this:

```
import NativeModules from 'react-native'
```

Comment: Thanks, Seems like this way it works. It is not null now. Do you know why it is not working with my approach ?

Comment: I think it was an issue of import. If you import it like this : import NativeModules from 'react-native' it will show the data.

Comment: Yes now NativeModules is not empty. Are there any documents on `RecordComponent` ? I tried by searching but did not see any documentation.

Comment: Even I didn't find anything on it hence I suggested you to go for requireNativeComponent